# Transpose using column names in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, unpivot

I have worked a bit in pivot/unpivot in Oracle SQL but this one seems little complex and need some help here. the below is my table design

| year | Comp_A_prev_yr_due_ct | Comp_A_prev_yr_due_amt | Comp_A_curr_yr_due_ct | Comp_A_Curr_yr_due_amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | 100 | 1000 | 101 | 1001 |

like this I have multiple companies as columns (each as a set of 4) and the report needs to be kinda be reader friendly

| Company | year | due_ct | due_amt | prev_or_curr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2019 | 100 | 1000 | prev |
| A | 2019 | 101 | 1001 | cur |

any help is gold here!!!! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT regexp_substr(company_prev_curr, '(.*?_){1}(.*?)_', 1, 1,'', 2) AS company
    ,year
    ,due_ct
    ,due_amt
    ,regexp_substr(company_prev_curr, '(.*?_){2}(.*?)_', 1, 1,'', 2) AS prev_curr
FROM test
unpivot(
        (due_ct,due_amt) 
         FOR company_prev_curr IN (
            (Comp_A_prev_yr_due_ct,Comp_A_prev_yr_due_amt),
            (Comp_A_curr_yr_due_ct,Comp_A_Curr_yr_due_amt)
            )
        ) u;
```

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=88d171fd093e2082dab683e8f1257dbd)

Comment: BINGO!!! there you go.. thanks worked like a charm..

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `cross apply`: lateral joins are a useful and efficient feature that many database support. In Oracle (assuming 12c or higher):

```
select t.year, x.*
from mytable t
cross apply (
    select 
        'A'                    as company, 
        comp_a_prev_yr_due_ct  as due_ct, 
        comp_a_prev_yr_due_amt as due_amt, 
        'prev'                 as prev_or_cur 
    from dual
    union all
    select 'A', comp_a_cur_yr_due_ct as due_ct, comp_a_cur_yr_due_amt, 'cur' from dual
) x
```